# Particle system lifetimes in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: opengl-es2, particles

I don't know how to work with my particle's lifetimes. My design is simple: each particle has a position, a speed and a lifetime. At each frame, each particle should update its position like this:

```
position.y = position.y + INCREMENT * speed.y
```

However, I'm having difficulties in choosing my `INCREMENT`. If I set it to some sort of `FRAME_COUNT`, it looks fine until `FRAME_COUNT` has to be set back to 0. The effect will be that all particles start over at the same time, which I don't want to happen. I want my particles sort of live "independent" of each other.

That's the reason I need a lifetime, but I don't know how to make use of it. I added a lifetime for each particle in the particle buffer, but I also need an individual increment that's updated on each frame, so that when `PARTICLE_INCREMENT = PARTICLE_LIFETIME`, each increment goes back to 0.

How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to implement a stateless particle system in a shader?
You need an extra vertex attribute: timeoffset.
Pick a random timeoffset value for each particle.

So your vertex attributes are:

```
startpos // vec per vertex
velocity // vec per vertex
timeoffset // scalar per vertex (N random values in [0..lifetime])
```

and you have the uniform variables:

```
currenttime. // scalar, one value for all vertices
lifetime. // scalar, one value for all vertices
```

Then in your shader:

```
t = currenttime + timeoffset;
t = t % lifetime;
pos = startpos + t * velocity;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is actually quite close to something I managed to implement after all (but that still had a few problems). I'll come back when I try your solution.

Comment: Tried your solution, works precisely as I wanted. :) Thank you.